# Error in insertion of multiple csv files into already existing mysql table

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to insert multiple csv files using sqlalchemy into an already existing mysql table named 'Trainstat' using the below code:

```
import os, sys
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://si:j9@localhost/db')
path= "/home/sh/T/f/"
dirs = os.listdir( path )
for file in dirs:
    df = pd.read_csv(path+file,sep='\n')
    df.to_sql('Trainstat', con=engine,dtype=None)
    print(df)
```

However, I seem to be getting an error `ValueError: Table 'Trainstat' already exists` and when I open my table, it has just one row inserted. What could be the possible error i my code? Is there some other way apart from sqlalchemy to insert csv files into an already existing table?

Answer (score 2):

The [`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html#pandas-dataframe-to-sql) method has an `if_exists` parameter:

> **if_exists** : *{‘fail’, ‘replace’, ‘append’}, default ‘fail’*
>
> How to behave if the table already exists.
>
> - fail: Raise a ValueError.
> - replace: Drop the table before inserting new values.
> - append: Insert new values to the existing table.

Also notice that it says:

> **Raises:**   ValueError
>
> > When the table already exists and if_exists is ‘fail’ (the default).

Since you haven't passed anything, you get the default, `fail`. So, after the table gets created for the first `DataFrame`, every subsequent `DataFrame` raises a `ValueError`, just as the docs say it will. And the `ValueError` tells you exactly what's wrong: `Table 'Trainstat' already exists`.

Since you want to append to the table rather than failing, just add `if_exists='append'` to your call.

Comment: I am getting the error `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'index' in 'field list'")` even though column index doesnt exist and the files are not being inserted

Answer (score 0):

This is because, the default parameter for the table existence in the **to_sql** method is to fail. The below changes to your code should solve your issue.

```
import os, sys
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://si:j9@localhost/db')
path= "/home/sh/T/f/"
dirs = os.listdir( path )
for file in dirs:
    df = pd.read_csv(path+file,sep='\n')
    df.to_sql('Trainstat', con=engine,dtype=None,if_exists='append')
    print(df)
```